# wvdial centos zoom modem redial issue

Tags: centos, modem

I have a zoom modem that dials out initially fine when I control-c out and try and redial it hangs, how do I tell wvdial to reset the modem before dialing I searched google but could not find the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttyS01
Baud = 57600
Init = ATZ
# ATZ will reset the modem before dialing
```

Comment: [Modem0]
Modem = /dev/ttyS0
Baud = 115200
SetVolume = 1
Dial Command = ATDT
Init1 = ATZ
Init3 = ATM1L1
FlowControl = CRTSCTS
Dial Attempts 4


[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttyS0
Baud = 115200
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ISDN = 0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Phone = 2090177
Phone1 = 2090545
Phone2 = 2744055
Phone3 = 2041800
Username = user
Password = pass

Comment: I have that in there but its still not resetting.

Comment: can you connect to the modem with minicom and run commands ? you could do some tests to see what it may be wrong - type in a few times atz and see if it echoes back ok then try atd1233444 some phone number to see if will dial - one more thing you could is to run wvdial with the atz string wvdial atz ... look into the man page